# Grub2 immediately boots into Linux

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, opensuse, grub2

OpenSuSE 13.2, running grub2.

SHORT VERSION:
Yesterday I had a normal grub2 boot menu and could choose to boot (successfully) into Linux or Windows.
Today, I see the grub2 header displayed for a fraction of a second, and then it proceeds to boot into Linux without giving me the usual 8 seconds of choice.
I had not changed the timeout or any other grub settings.

I have now tried `grub2-install /dev/sda` and `grub2-mkconfig`, to no noticeable effect. The generated `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` looks fine; it definitely has an entry for Windows.

LONG VERSION:
I had a spot of bother yesterday, and ended up re-installing openSuSE, letting it create a /home directory on the (btrfs) system partition, and then replacing that with the (encrypted) xfs partition that I had been using up until the trouble.
It may be at that point that grub broke (although I don't see why), because I know I was still able to boot into Windows via the grub menu after the reinstall but before resurrecting /home.

UPDATE:
The grub trouble may have started when I tried to exit openSuSE by selecting the Windows entry from the shutdown menu as the OS to boot into next (see image).[image]
Note that that entry is a bit odd, since Windows is not a "snapper" btrfs snapshot.
Anyway, I now also see that `/boot/grub2/grubenv` has this:

```
# GRUB Environment Block
saved_entry=0
next_entry=Bootable snapshot #$snapshot_num>Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
###########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
```

Could that be the issue? Can/should I unset next_entry? Or delete the entire line? What are the 914 '#'s about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that weird entry in grubenv was the issue.

I renamed the file and rebooted and I have gloriously full grub2 functionality again.

Thanks for [rubber-ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), SuperUsers.